# Rails 5.1.4 active storage MissingModelIdError

Tags: amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Rails newbie here. I am trying to upload a file to S3 via active storage through a background job. Set up everything as mentioned in this article (https://keithpblog.org/post/active-storage-on-amazon-s3/.)
When I run the background job I get this error. Searched google but I couldn't find anything relevant.
Can someone please help me out?

The below is how my model looks

```
class ReportOutput < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :output_file
end
```

This is how I am calling it. (not sure if this is correct way)

```
ReportOutput.new.output_file.attach(io: File.open('./test.xlsx'), filename: 'test.xlsx')
```

This is the error I get.

```
Job exception: #<URI::GID::MissingModelIdError: Unable to create a Global ID for ReportOutput without a model id.>
```

Comment: Can you also add your ReportOutputsController to question?

Comment: I used carrierwave with mongo and moved away from using S3. Will get to uploading file to S3 after upgrading my rails version to 5.2